# knitr does not compile an html document (RStudio) and no errors reported

Tags: rstudio, knitr

I am trying to re-run my script to generate html document by knitr via RStudio (pressing the button "Knit HTML".
Everything seems to be ok - no errors reported.
But no an html document is generated and the progress mark is frozen at 57% of completion. Everything looks like knitr or RStudio has "completed" compelation.

I cant define the likely reason of such a situation. Maybe, the reason is the lack of RAM at some critical processing stage.

Would be grateful for a piece of advice.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. In doing so, you will either find the solution yourself or make your question answerable. Currently, this is not reproducible and thus cannot be answered.

Comment: Verify that your code works as is.  For example: did you use library() to import all necessary packages?  Usually these errors should give an error, but can't hurt to double check.  Also, try exporting a PDF or word document.  Do either of these work?  Another question I have, did you ever successfully knit HTML before now?  Just trying to cover some gaps in your question.